# Make content remain in one line on all phone devices

Tags: jquery, html, css, menu, responsive

I have created a hamburger mobile menu, and I tried to include contact information in that menu.

I tried two approaches: the first one worked on all devices except iPhones and other devices who mainly use safari. Then the line with the text would break.

This approach also involved media queries. I must say that when you inspect this with your desktop it looks fine, but on actual phone devices the line breaks into two after the icons.

Here's the source code of this approach:

```html
<div class="elementor-widget-container">
  <div class="elementor-text-editor elementor-clearfix">
    <p class="makeSmall" style="text-align: center;">
      <a href="mailto:maya@mayabarber.co.il">
        <img class="email-mobile" src="http://mayabarber.co.il/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/Untitled-1.svg" width="33" height="33">&nbsp;</a>
      <a href="https://www.facebook.com/mayabarbercontrolcenter/"><img class="facebook-mobile" src="http://mayabarber.co.il/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/Untitled-2.svg" width="33" height="33">&nbsp;<label style="color: #61f6ff;" data-mce-fragment="1">|</label></a>&nbsp;<span class="" style="color: #001a71;" data-mce-fragment="1"><a href="tel:0526582643">&nbsp;052-6582643</a></span></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Second approach I have tried, kinda worked but the icons looked smaller than the amount of the px I have defined and it looked all messy.

```html
<div class="elementor-text-editor elementor-clearfix elementor-inline-editing" data-elementor-setting-key="editor" data-elementor-inline-editing-toolbar="advanced">
  <p class="makeSmall" style="text-align: center;">
    <a href="mailto:maya@mayabarber.co.il">
      <img class="email-mobile" src="http://mayabarber.co.il/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/Untitled-1.svg" width="33" height="33">&nbsp;</a>
    <a href="https://www.facebook.com/mayabarbercontrolcenter/"><img class="facebook-mobile" src="http://mayabarber.co.il/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/Untitled-2.svg" width="33" height="33">&nbsp;<label style="color: #61f6ff;" data-mce-fragment="1">|</label></a>&nbsp;<span class="" style="color: #001a71;" data-mce-fragment="1"><a href="tel:0526582643">&nbsp;052-6582643</a></span></p>
</div>
```

CSS code:

```css
.mobilemenucontact {
  white-space: nowrap;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
}

#mobilemenucontact {
  white-space: nowrap;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 375px) {
  .makeSmall {
    font-size: 95%;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 375px) {
  .email-mobile {
    width: 28px;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 375px) {
  .facebook-mobile {
    width: 28px;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 375px) {
  .column-contact {
    padding: 5px 30px;
  }
}

.active {
  border-bottom: 2.11px solid #61f6ff;
  padding: 4px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin-bottom: 4px;
}
```

So I'm not sure which approach to go with and I just want the two icons and the phone number to remain in online line no matter what browser or phone device it is. I also want the spaces between there to be equal, and I want the icons to be 33px width.

Here's the website where you can inspect both approaches: [www.mayabarber.co.il](http://www.mayabarber.co.il)

Here's is the way I want it to look if you prefer generating your own responsive HTML/CSS code and ignoring my clumsy attempts:

[image]

Thank you!

Comment: Do you mean this break? https://i.stack.imgur.com/HCHgY.png

Comment: Yes! I want it to be just like in the picture- one line.

Comment: Rozi, what is the status of your question? I saw that you changed some code in your website..

Answer (score 0):

As per given link above, I guess your issue will resolve if you just add the following `CSS` to the media screen where you want to apply this changes.

Also you can reduce padding or set this in `%` instead of `px`.

```
.elementor-nav-menu a{
   display: inline-flex;
}
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Hi,
Your solution partly helped! We're almost there.
It's still behaving a bit bad on Safari browser on iPhones. Look at the picture: https://ibb.co/huPxC8

Comment: Refering to the unequal spaces between the elements

Comment: After adding links to the html it got messed up on other devices too.

Answer (score 0):

Your markup is over complicated, so I've created a list with the links and aligned it using `flex-box` & `align-items:center`.

```css
.social-links {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
}

.social-links li {
  padding: 10px 4px;
}

.social-links li.with-separator {
  border-left: 1px solid #61f6ff;
  margin-left: 16px;
  padding-left: 20px;
}

.social-links li img {
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.social-links a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #494c4f;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 375px) {
  .social-links {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .social-links li.with-separator {
    border-left: 0;
    border-top: 1px solid #61f6ff;
    margin-left: 0;
    padding-left: 4px;
  }
}
```

```html
<ul class="social-links">
  <li>
    <a href="mailto:maya@mayabarber.co.il" class="icon"><img class="email-mobile" src="http://mayabarber.co.il/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/Untitled-1.svg" width="33" height="33"></a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="https://www.facebook.com/mayabarbercontrolcenter/" class="icon"><img class="facebook-mobile" src="http://mayabarber.co.il/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/Untitled-2.svg" width="33" height="33"></a>
  </li>
  <li class="with-separator"><a href="tel:0526582643">052-6582643</a></li>
  <li class="with-separator"><a href="tel:048201996">04-8201996</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks, but adding that prevents the hamburger from opening up on mobile devices, and on my website preview all elements are below each other and not side by side for some reason.